# Xcode archive multiple method named setScale: found

Tags: ios, xcode, core-plot

When I'm trying to archive an ipa file,

In code I don't understand (Core plot downloaded a while ago), in `CPTGraphHostingView.m`, in `-(void)handlePinchGesture:(id)aPinchGestureRecognizer` there is this `[pinchGestureRecognizer setScale:1.0f];`

While archiving, XCode complains "Multiple methods named 'setScale:' found.

In my normal testing build (simulator or running to device) the error doesn't show up.

I am wondering why such thing isn't showing up in my regular build but only during archiving? I have not discovered what the problem is yet. Maybe I can try to update Core plot first.

Comment: Change `id` to `UIPinchGestureRecognizer *`. This will eliminate the error.

Comment: It does. Why is that?

Comment: When you use a specific class there is no ambiguity. The compiler sees a reference to `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and knows that it has a `scale` property so it knows what to do with the `setScale:` method call. But with `id` is doesn't know what class it is at compile time. So it searches the known methods it has seen so far and discovers two (or more) `setScale:` methods. Most likely they take different parameters or return different values so the compiler can't compile the right amount of stack to deal with the parameter/return value and gives up with the warning.

Comment: Why is that when building regularly it DOES know but when archiving it doesn't?

Comment: That part I don't know. It could be a difference between a debug and release build or some optimization.